# About PHP file redirect

Tags: php, redirect

Might be silly question

I've seen many way of redirect to redirect from php file to another pages

like

```
if(somethingwentwrong)
{
    redirect coded
}
```

one is header

```
header(location:'xx');
```

or meta refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=xx">
```

or echo out script

```
echo "<script>window.location='xx'</script>
```

and exit/die

```
die(//redirect code maybe "<script>" or header(location:) )
```

and anything more else that can redirect to another page from php file (that you can tell me if there isn't in here)

what i want to know is

- the semantic of each one?
- what situation should each one use for? / and why?

ex. header(location:'xx'); meaning / and use in situation like ...

Thanks

Comment: They all do the same thing essentially. If I were you, I'd avoid the meta refresh if you're doing it from within your PHP.

Comment: i just want to know what should i do to break whole file to compile if something went wrong then // and if user don't turn on the javascript what should be use instead of <noscript> in the head of page then :(

Comment: The best way to go is simply `die(header("Location: http://www.example.com/where/you/wanna/go"))`.

Comment: totally best and simply because some user turn off javascript but if something like that happen how the user know what's went wrong without alert :O?

Comment: You could send them to an error page..

Comment: is it possible to redirect back with variable something like [link](http://blablabla.com?error=1) and use variable to print out something or do something // just thinking

Comment: Yes that is entirely possible. And in your `/error` page, you'd just get the that `$_GET` param and find the error for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

header is generally a good way to go, as it gives instructions directly to the web browser on how to convert a file.  The javascript approach is good, however it depends on the client-side settings to do the redirect. While it will work in most cases, it's not perfect.

meta-refresh will work but it can cause the browser to break the back-button (a usability no-no)

all above said, I'd stick with header redirects